# Redirecting http://example.com to https://www.dummy.com/ via .htaceess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

A client of mine wants to change their domain name, but wants to keep their Google ranking. To do this, they've pointed two domain names to the same IP, but we're having an issue where if you visit the site via the old domain, you get a security certificate warning and the page just loads with the old domain name.

What I'd like to do is detect when someone's coming to the site via the old domain and rewrite it to the new domain. For example, if they where to visit `example.com/some-page.htm`, it would rewrite to `https://www.dummy.com/some-page.htm`.

I found this code snippet somewhere that purports to do this, but it just brings the site down:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dummy.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is a WordPress site, so I'm using the normal WordPress rewrite rules, and I'm using the [HTML5 Boiler Plate .htacess](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess) to enable http > https redriects, non-www > www redirects, and force HTTP Strict Transport Security, if any of that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change condition to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.dummy.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

However keep in mind if you visit `https://exampl.com` and certificate is for `dummy.com` then SSL cert warning will still be there because **SSL handshakes before `mod_rewrite` is invoked for redirecting to new site**.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: This worked great, thanks so much. SSL issue is slightly problematic, but I've recommend a solution for that to my client so it's in their hands.